# Get the subscription email from a specific topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Im trying to get the email of a subscriptor in a specific topic.

But with code below Im getting a dictonary, but I just want the email:

```
conn = boto.sns.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
test = conn.get_all_subscriptions_by_topic("arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:8274142742:testtopic")
print test
```

I was trying something like this:

```
test2 = test['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse']['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResult']['Subscriptions'][0]
```

But again, I dont get only the email.

Do you know how can I get only the email here?

With `print test`, Im getting this:

```
 {u'ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse':
 {u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u'd0cc4614-c74-580-b87-0abc0354042'}, 
 u'ListSubscriptionsByTopicResult': {u'NextToken': None, u'Subscriptions': 
 [{u'Owner': u'8472474872', u'Endpoint': u'email@testemail.email', u'Protocol': u'email', 
 u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:8274142742:testtopic',
 u'SubscriptionArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:8274142742:testtopic:764201g4-812-4e26-a234-3ed4c2732d'}]}}}
```

Comment: Can you paste the sample of the output by `print test` for reference?

Comment: Yes, I updated now the question with that print!

Comment: let me know if [how to parse json where key is variable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970436/how-to-parse-json-where-key-is-variable-in-python) can fix your issue or not.